# Dynamics 365 (online) not showing "Editable Grid" option in the entity controls section

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-365

I am trying to create an "editable grid" for one of my entities in Dynamics 365 CRM but there is no option available for creating an editable grid in the entities control. In other words: `Settings>Customization>Customize the System>Entities>*entity_name*>Controls` tap `"Add Control"` and there are only two options: "Calendar Control" and "Timeline Control." There is no option for "Editable Grids" as shown at this link: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt791766.aspx A screenshot of what I'm seeing:

[image: Add Control Options]

Comment: On what entity you are trying to add this control?

Comment: I would like to ask what entity is this and whether you are using a user with System Administrator privileges?

Comment: It is on the contacts entity and yes I have System Administrator privileges

Comment: Was this upgraded from a lower version or is this a new instance?

Comment: This is a new instance

Comment: See my answer below if it helps clarify what's happening on your Dynamics instance.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your instance is Dynamics 365. To do this, follow the steps below.

- click Dynamics 365 menu
- click Admin

[image]

- expand Admin Centers
- click Dynamics 365

[image]

- click EDIT

[image]

- change Instance type to Sandbox
- click next

[image]

- click save

[image]

- click RESET

[image]

- make sure the Target version supports editable grid

[image]

This might not solve your problem, but at least we are sure that we are using an instance that supports editable grid. I do hope this helps in some way.